# Rotate userobject in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm trying to create a graphical layout of warehouse utilization.

I've created a userobject with a datawindow that retrieves each location and shows all relevant data. I'm placing these on a window using the openuserobject function, this is all fine.

Now, some locations are to be shown horizontally (left to right), is there any way to rotate an userobject??

[image: Excample of wanted rotation]

Br
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, no.

I assume a sideways graph is not suitable for your project.  That being the case you need to design a datawindow object which takes the data you retrieve, calculates the widths of each data piece as a percentage of the total, then draws a rectangle object.

You can create these types of objects within a datawindow control. Generally this would be a series of 'Modify' statements. Here is one example from the PowerBuilder help:

```
    string modstring


>     modstring = 'create rectangle(Band=background X="206" Y="6"  height="69" width="1363" brush.hatch="6" brush.color="12632256" 
> pen.style="0" pen.width="14" pen.color="268435584" background.mode="2"
> background.color="-1879048064" name=rect1 )'


    dw_cust.Modify(modstring)
```

This creates a rectangle in the background of a datawindow.

Any specific behavior for the object should be written as generic as possible any you would want to come up with some type of naming convention for the rectangles for use in events such as mouseovers, clicks, and etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt, controlling X and Y of the objects in the datawindow might be the solution.